# Remove iOS hover shadow js/css

Tags: javascript, ios, css, css-animations

I am creating a "hover" effect on a mobile web app I am working on using `touchstart` and `touchend`.

```
$('.touchMe').bind('touchstart', function(){
    $(this).addClass('spin');
  }).bind('touchend', function(){
      $(this).removeClass('spin');
  });
```

Pretty simple and it works quite well.  I used `-webkit-user-select: none;` to remove the iOS magnifier when pressing the element.  This also works quite well.

I am left with a situation where when I touch the element, the animation works.  When I stop touching the element, the animation stops, GREAT!

However, I am left with a weird shadow that covers the animated element:

[image]

The blue element spins as expected, but there is a stationary gray selection shadow.  My question is, if possible, how can I remove this shadow?

Comment: Could you create a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: This seems to work: http://jsbin.com/refebumoju/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Here is my code.  View on mobile